# Can I stream GeoJSON data in openlayers, using Angular6+

Tags: vector-layer, angular2, openlayers, stream

I am using angular 6 and openlayers 5.

Angular 6 combined with RxJS can easily create streams. I was thinking to use RxJS streams in order to feed GeoJSON data to ol5 vector layers. Why? Because streams supposedly bring data back as soon as they have them and they do not wait for all the data to be available. So, when the GeoJSON data are too big, this can make for better user experience -users dont wait for all the data to load.

But, I dont know if ol5 vector layers work this way. I dont know if they accept streams at all. I dont understand clearly if [loading strategies](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector.html#~LoadingStrategy) support streams or not.

Anyway, should I try to make this work somehow?

Is it possible, or vector layers wont support streams anyway?

---

Here is a quick example/explanation of angular streams, that is not geo-related, just in case you dont have a clue about angular

`results` is an Observable, with a pre-defined structure. Since it is an observable, we can assign to it a stream that brings back data -we can observe it

the structure

```
class SearchResult {
  constructor(
    public id: any,
    public name: string
  ) {}
}
```

define the results

```
results: Observable<SearchResult[]>;
```

so, results can be equal to a stream `pipe` that brings back data from a `searchName` function that is triggered every time the value of a form changes -the `this.myform.valueChanges` part. So, as I type in a search field, the words are send to the function and I get streamed answers back

```
this.results = this.myform.valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap( formdata => this.myService.searchName(formdata.name)),
);
```

For a more detailed explanation, check [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/)